# Tor browser not working on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: apt, package-management, python, firefox, tor

When I run `torbrowser-launcher` installed from the repository I get the following error:

```
$ torbrowser-launcher 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/torbrowser-launcher", line 29, in <module>
    import torbrowser_launcher
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .common import Common, SHARE
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py", line 55, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import gtk2reactor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/gtk2reactor.py", line 23, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import _glibbase
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/_glibbase.py", line 20, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import base, posixbase, selectreactor
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 26, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import fdesc, main, error, abstract, defer, threads
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1366, in <module>
    @attr.s
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 's'
```

even though I installed `attrs` via `sudo pip install attrs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install Tor from the official website and execute the program after extracting it.
Link: https://www.torproject.org/download/download